# Paging partialview with PagedList

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, pagedlist

i have a partialview that has tabular data..
i am using [PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/1.16.0.0) for paging.

it works good with a normal view, but when I tried to put it on a partial view, when I click next or any other pages, it just refreshes the whole page and my view breaks :(

I want to refresh the partialview only meaning when I perform pagination, i just want to change the partialview not the whole view.

this is the code for pagination i my partialview...

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("StudentList", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )
```

i tried to put Ajax.ActionLink instead of Url.Action with no success...
any help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using paging in partial view, asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822352/using-paging-in-partial-view-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, I found the answer.
Someone else had the similar question that I just found out...

here is it:
[Using paging in partial view, asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822352/using-paging-in-partial-view-asp-net-mvc)

and it works just fine..

Answer (score 1):

You can use PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing for ajaxifying the page no link, which returns the partial view.

**In Controller:**

```
 if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
    //viewModel=your viewModel
    return PartialView("viewModel");
  }
```

**In View:**

```
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("StudentList", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter }),PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing( new AjaxOptions(){  HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "student_table"}) )
```